# Por que dá pra apagar uma declaração de "lançamento" de exceção da assinatura de um método herdado?

Tags: java, exceção

Gostaria de saber pois não entendi essa parte, é por ser uma declaração de que ele pode "lançar" uma exceção?

```
//EXEMPLO
public abstract class Personagem{
    public abstract void atacar() throws Exception;
}
//Atacar é abstrato
//logo abaixo quando eu herdo eu posso tirar o throws Exception da assinatura.
public class Mago extends Personagem{
    public void atacar(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta. Seja mais claro por favor. Coloque o código que você tem dúvida.

Comment: espero ter deixado mais concreto o que eu quis dizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `atacar()` está sendo sobrescrito na subclasse `Mago`, ou seja, o método não é invocado na superclasse `Personagem` e não deverá lançar uma exceção.